# How can I set the position of a mesh before I add it to the scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js, I want to add a mesh to a position in the scene

I've tried:

```
// mesh is an instance of THREE.Mesh
// scene is an instance of THREE.Scene
scene.add(mesh)
scene.updateMatrixWorld(true)
mesh.matrixWorld.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 100))
scene.updateMatrix()
```

BUT it didn't affect anything.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the documentation over here:
[http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Mesh)
As you can see on the top of the docu-page, Mesh inherits from "*Object3D*". That means that you can use all methods or properties that are provided by Object3D. So click on the "*Object3D*" link on the docu-page and check the properties list. You will find the property "*.position*". Click on "*.position*" to see what data-type it is. Paha..its *Vector3*.

So try to do the following:

```
// scene is an instance of THREE.Scene
scene.add(mesh);
mesh.position.set(100, 100, 100);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use mesh.position.set(x,y,z) because you will do not need force updating, if you set mesh.position = xxx, you only changing the object attribute, not always moving object in scene real time. position.set is more coplex and always move object to destination and refresh buffer, lights, shadows etc ... in once.

Comment: I tried this, and cannot figure out what it is actually doing. If I draw a point, it is in the correct place. But if I create a mesh, and try to set the position, it just appears in some apparently random place.

Comment: in my case : mesh.position does not change the position. but the  mesh.position.set(x,y,z) as mentioned by Martin  works perfectly.

Comment: In the case of a complex mesh, `position` refers of what? Some kind of "center"?

Comment: `set` is defined in the `Vector3` class definition. In order to find it you must navigate like so: Mesh > Object3d > Object3d.position > Vector3 > Vector3.set - fortunately this author also provided a example of working code.

Answer (score 37):

i saw it on a github earlier.  (three.js r71 )

```
mesh.position.set(100, 100, 100);
```

and can be done for individuals

```
mesh.position.setX(200);  
mesh.position.setZ(200);
```

reference: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3

**detailed explanation is below:**

since mesh.position is "Vector3". Vector3() has setX() setY() and setZ() methods. we can use it like this.

```
mesh.position = new THREE.Vector3() ; //see position is Vector3()
vector1 = new THREE.Vector3();   

mesh.position.setX(100);  //or  this
vector1.setX(100)         // because all of them is Vector3()
camera1.position.setZ(100); // or this
light1.position.setY(100)   // applicable to any object.position
```

Comment: This works for me, while the chysmann's answer doesn't, though I can't explain why it doesn't/wouldn't. Can you elaborate on what you meant by "saw it on github"?

Comment: i saw it on a github three.js page . but icant find the source right now

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use mesh.position.set(x,y,z) because you will do not need force updating, if you set mesh.position = xxx, you only changing the object attribute, not always moving object in scene real time. position.set is more coplex and always move object to destination and refresh buffer, lights, shadows etc ... in once.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As of R69 (the latest distribution available from Google CDN) attempting to assign a value to `mesh.position` should not be done as it is `read only`, resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'position' of [object Object]`.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use **`Vector3`** to set position.

```
   let group = new THREE.Group();

   // position of box
   let vector = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10);
   
     // add wooden Box
   let woodenBox = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, woodMaterial);

    //update postion
    woodenBox.position.copy(vector);

  // add to scene
   group.add(woodenBox)
   this.scene.add(group);
```

Comment: Where do you use `position`?

Comment: In vector 10,10,10

Comment: this examples really takes a Vector3 as inputs and sets it in one go

Answer (score 2):

If some one looking for way to update position from Vector3

```
const V3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)            // Create variable in zero position
const box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material) // Create an object
Object.assign(box.position, V3)                // Put the object in zero position
```

OR

```
const V3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)            // Create variable in zero position
const box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material) // Create an object
box.position.copy(V3)
```