# Add two cubes to group and make them adjacent in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add two cubes to the same group and have them rendered adjacently.

```
var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());  
var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

cube1.position = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0 , 0 );
cube2.position = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1 , 0 );

var cubeGroup = new THREE.Group();  

cubeGroup.add( cube1 );
cubeGroup.add( cube2 );

scene.add(cubeGroup);
```

The output seems to show two cubes at the same location.

[image]

I checked that those are two different cubes by stretching them along orthogonal components during initialization...

```
var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(2,1,1), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());  
var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,2,1), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
```

So the result is that two rectangular prisms are rendered/centered along the origin:

[image]

So my questions are the following:

- Generally speaking, `whats wrong and how do I make it work?`
- Speaking in terms of Groups, `are groups used to compose meshes into single units?(I want to rotate many adjacent cubes along a central axis)`
- Speaking in terms of scale, `Do CubeGeometries operate on the same scale that vectors and positions operate on?`

Comment: As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223249 you need to do `mesh.position.set(x,y,z)` and not `mesh.position = `

Comment: It works!  If you can post it as a self contained answer, I'll mark it as answered!